# Parse command `watch` with `InputStream`

Tags: java, linux, shell

I have this command:

```
new ProcessBuilder()
    .command("watch", "-n2", "ps", "-q", IdeProcess.pid, "-o", "rss");
```

How I can to parse output from this command?

When I get `InputStream` of this `Process`, I get an empty line every time.

--
I used to restart the command via Java, creating a new thread and all over again. Now, I decided to implement it with the help of `watch`.

Snippet of code:

```
var process = processBuilder.start();
var stream = process.getInputStream();
var input = new StringBuilder();
int n;

//while (isOpenIO) {
    while ((n = stream.read()) != -1)
        input.append((char) n);
    if (input.length() > 0)
        System.out.println("NON EMPTY");
    if (input.length() > 3) {
        String text = input.substring(input.indexOf("\n") + 1, input.length() - 1);
        String modified = text.replaceAll("\\B(?=(\\d{3})+(?!\\d))", ",");
        System.out.println("RAM: " + modified + " Mb"));
    }
//}
```

Comment: Can you please share with us your whole code snippet? Without it is hard anyone to determine your error.

Comment: Yes, I updated post

Comment: I assume that input is a StringBuilder correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: NIce. OK, I haven't used the watch command so I'm familiar with it, but it seems that this will not return but it rather queries the processe's details every 2 seconds correct? With that in mind this means that you'll be receiving an endless inputstream for the execution of the command, meaning again that the method running this will never return. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want every 2 seconds get memory usage of process. In order not to create every 2 seconds, a new `Thread` decided to use `watch`.

How then can I get the output of this command? After all, the terminal updates the data, somehow getting the output.

Comment: OK in that case consider that since the command runs endlessly, you'll be getting an endless inputstream, meaning that you'll never exit the while loop. I suggest you reconsider your approach and create a new Thread that runs on a timer (every 2 seconds) that queries the memory usage of a given process.

Comment: Ah, I might not have used the new `Thread` (Previously, I created a new `Thread` for the `InputStream` and waited for the process to complete with `waitFor`). You could simply transfer cycle `isOpenIO` on top of all the code that is listed in the post. To remove the `watch`. Thank you! I don't know why I didn't figure it out from the start.

Comment: Actually I'm prepping up a small example for your if you would like to have a look.

Comment: Well, I'd be interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very crude example of something like what you want to achieve is the following. This uses a single threaded executor service running at 2 seconds intervals, polling the memory usage of a given process.

At the moment this only prints the result out to the console, but you can tinker around with it to return a `Future` so you can get your result.

I hope this helps.

```
private static ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            try {
                Process process = new ProcessBuilder("ps", "-p", "2782", "-o", "%mem").redirectErrorStream(true).start();
                try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()))) {
                    String s = reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
                    System.out.println(s);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```

For reference, I'm using `ps` here to get the memory usage of the process in question, but you can use whatever you like.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot that there is a `ScheduledExecutorService`. But I do not use `BufferedReader`. I'm not familiar with it, and it seems to be created every time as a new object.

https://github.com/MrChebik/Coconut-IDE/blob/f14713af5a644e714dda03a7c0451c448658a1d9/src/main/java/ru/mrchebik/plugin/debug/PluginDebug.java#L42-L59

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I understood, now I use `BufferedReader` in my project. It is more profitable than an `InputStream`. Thank you again!

Comment: I did it yesterday, but for those with a reputation below 15, the result is not displayed publicly.